# Why do Instantiated LineRenderers not allow BakeMesh in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My scene has a GameObject as its root, and a LineRenderer as its child.
[image: Scene hierarchy: GameWorld>Path]

When calling BakeMesh on the LineRenderer, it works fine. If I copy the LineRenderer using `Instantiate`, then call BakeMesh, it fails.

Simplified code:

```
LineRenderer lineRenderer = m_GameWorld.GetComponentInChildren<LineRenderer>();
Transform rootTransform = m_GameWorld.transform;

Debug.Log("Baking mesh using a the original LineRenderer");
m_Path = lineRenderer;
m_Path.BakeMesh(new Mesh(), true);

Debug.Log("Baking mesh using a copy of LineRenderer");
m_Path = Instantiate(lineRenderer, rootTransform);
m_Path.BakeMesh(new Mesh(), true);

Debug.Log("Done");
```

The output of this is:

```
Baking mesh using a the original LineRenderer
Baking mesh using a copy of LineRenderer
Mesh '': abnormal mesh bounds - most likely it has some invalid vertices (+/-inifinity or NANs) due to errors exporting.
Mesh bounds min=(-244756620798551190644195328.00, 0.00, 0.00), max=(0.00, 5.21, 21341459879620077536841802664902656.00). Please make sure the mesh is exported without any errors.
Done
```

The error does not occur when `useTransform`, the second argument of `BakeMesh`, is set to False.

This seems likely to be a Unity bug - but it's possible I'm misunderstanding the intricacies of `Instantiate`?

Comment: Anyway what good is it to pass in a `new Mesh` without storing the reference anywhere?

Comment: This is a minimal reproducible example. The actual code is more complex. Did you downvote my question for that reason?

Comment: I didn't downvote anything .. just asked to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Unity bug and has been fixed in 2022.1.X: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/linerenderer-dot-bakemesh-fails-when-called-on-instantiated-copy

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. Using `m_Path.BakeMesh(new Mesh(), false)` fixed it for me. So the scale of the transformation somehow breaks it. However, setting the scale before calling BakeMesh did not seem to fix it.

Comment: I have the same workaround- it seems like a Unity bug then?